# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 - Disable custom error redirection for controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, redirect, custom-errors

I have a controller with a series of actions that return jsonp.  My problem is that with custom errors enabled, my jquery ajax calls do not "error" when there is a hard server error. So, I need to disable custom error redirection just for the controller, or if I have to, for each action in that controller.

Is there any way that I can disable the redirection when an error happens only on those actions, but still return an error code to the client so that ajax can handle the error?

EDIT:

I'll expand with some code.  Firstly, I am using the configuration for custom errors.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error/ServerError">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/AccessDenied" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/ServerError" />
  <error statusCode="999" redirect="~/Error/ServerError" />
</customErrors>
```

Then, I have my own exception reporting attribute.  This attribute is applied to a base controller class that implements IController.  All of my controllers inherit from this base controller, so that they all have error reporting built in any time there is a server error.

```
public sealed class HandleErrorAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        base.OnException(context);
        RaiseErrorSignal(context.Exception);
    }

    private static void RaiseErrorSignal(Exception ex)
    {
        IExceptionHandler handler = Resolve();

        handler.HandleError(ex.GetBaseException());
    }

    private static IExceptionHandler Resolve()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Locate<IExceptionHandler>();

    }
}
```

And I have a controller with methods like this

```
public JsonpResult DoSomething(string sessionId /*...more params...*/)
{
    //Do work

    return new JsonpResult() { Data = new { } };
}
```

On only this controller/these actions, I want to disable the redirection so that the error code is returned to the client.  The error still needs to be thrown, but somehow the custom error mode needs to be changed to Off for only this request and only the duration of the request.

Comment: Are you using the [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx) on your controller/base controller, or is it just the standard ASP.NET `<customErrors />` element in your config?

Comment: It is the standard custom errors.  I wrote my own exception handler that simply mails me the server error and then continues allowing the app to do the built in redirection.  I was hoping there was a way I could write an attribute to programatically disable custom errors per request and attach that to the controller.

Comment: Do you want to disable it for specific controller/action or for specific action type (ajax method)?

Comment: @frennky - because all of these jsonp requests use the same action result, it could be by action result type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are ajax calls, you could try something like this:

```
public sealed class HandleErrorAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (!filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            base.OnException(context);
            RaiseErrorSignal(context.Exception);
        }
        else
        {
            //Respond to ajax call with error message
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to throw back an error message, but MVC uses the status code to perform the redirect automatically after this point.

Comment: Have you tried this? I thought redirect is done in base.OnException(context) method?

Answer (score 3):

I took the answer provided by @frennky and expanded on it a little bit.  I am setting the HTTP response code and letting the error handler on the jQuery side handle it.

In my case I am integrating with a legacy webforms app that uses an ASP.NET custom error page that trapped all of my errors.  All execeptions were being swallowed and the jQuery AJAX call appeared to complete normally.  The HTML of the custom error page was being returned to my jQuery AJAX success function.  I wanted a way to utilize the error handling provided by jQuery.  This approach accomplishes that goal.

Here is my custom HandleErrorAttribute:

```
public class HandleAjaxErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            base.OnException(filterContext);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Log the error here.
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = filterContext.Exception.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Javascript function that gets called when the jQuery AJAX request fails (simplified for this example):

```
function HandleAjaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.statusText);
}
```

Comment: `StatusDescription` doesn't seem to work nice with Unicode text (on Chromium browsers at least)... Those browsers are driving me nuts... :(